Kinde auth with Next.js
I have build middleware with Next.js and Kinde. My protected route is '/profile'.
import { withAuth } from '@kinde-oss/kinde-auth-nextjs/server';

export default function middleware(req: Request) {
  return withAuth(req);
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/profile'],
};

import UserCard from '@/app/_components/user-card/user-card';
import { getUserFromDB } from '@/db/queries/user';
import { getKindeServerSession } from '@kinde-oss/kinde-auth-nextjs/server';
import classes from './Profile.module.css';

export default async function Profile() {
  const { getUser } = getKindeServerSession();
  const user = await getUser();

  if(user === null) {
    redirect('/login')
  }

  const user = await getUserFromDB(kindeUser.id);

  return (
    <div className={classes.profile}>
      <UserCard user={user} />
    </div>
  );
}

But when I call from '/profile' I still get that user can be null. In what case that user can be null? Also what would be good solution when user is null? I would prefer not to write if(user===null) redirect('/login) in every component that needs getUser() function and is part of protected routes.
Is it ok to consider that user is not null if check from middleware is ok?
I expect that user is not null if getUser() is called in protected route.

From Next.js docs for middleware:

Middleware should be lightweight and respond quickly or it can cause delays in page load. Heavy computational tasks or long-running processes should be done within dedicated Route Handlers.

Just getting the user session from Kinde doesn't seem to be a heavy task (depends on how quickly Kinde and Next Application servers are communicating). So if you want the middleware to trigger only for protected routes, retrieveing user authentication inside it seems to me like an appropriate solution.
The problem here is that I'm not sure if it is easy to pass user session further to protected routes from middleware. Instead, you may create a context component to handle the retrieval of user session data and nest all protected routes inside it in a layout component.
Moreover, there is another way to check just if the user is authenticated that may be a little bit cleaner for middleware:
const { isAuthenticated } = getKindeServerSession();
const isUserAuthenticated = await isAuthenticated();

With this boolean, you may test the path against protected routes inside the middleware function if you ever need to use middleware for other routes in the future.
